# concurrency test in jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, concurrency, jmeter

I am new to jmeter, and I would like to do a test in which I send 500 requests per second, this for 10 seconds
The configuration I have is:

[image]

I would like to know if my configuration is correct or it can be done better

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration means:

1. 5000 users will be kicked off in 10 seconds, i.e. each second 500 users  will be started
2. Once started the users will start executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down
3. The actual number of requests per second will depend on the application response time.

In your case you will only be able to achieve 500 requests per second if your application response time will be 1 second precisely. If it will be more - you will get less requests per second and vice versa.

If you need to send 500 requests per second for 10 seconds sharp I would suggest using [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) combination.

The Throughput Shaping Timer needs to be set up like this:

[image]

And the concurrency thread group like this:

[image]

The configuration is for example only, in your case the number of threads required to conduct 500 request per second load might be different and again in mainly depends on the application response time.